# Generate IFCRoad via IFCOpenShell

Tags: python, django, geometry, postgis, ifc

I have this model

```
class Tramif_PCI_agrup(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)    
    pci = models.FloatField(null=True)
    geom = models.LineStringField(geography=True, srid=4326, null=True)
```

That i want to translate into an IFCRoad using the IFCOpenShell library to get a final IFC file with every Object with its geom and its PCI value.

This is what i tried but it didnt work

```
# Get all objects from the Tramif_PCI_agrup model
            tramif_pci_agrups = Tramif_PCI_agrup.objects.all()
            

            # Create a blank model
            ifc_file = ifcopenshell.file(schema='IFC4X3')

            # Create an IfcRoad entity
            road = ifc_file.create_entity("IfcRoad")
            road.Name = "Simple Road"

            # Fetch objects from the model and iterate over them
            
            for tramif_object in tramif_pci_agrups:
                # Extract geometry and PCI values from the model object
                geom = tramif_object.geom
                pci = tramif_object.pci

                # Convert the geometry to WKT format
                wkt_geom = geom.wkt

                # Create an IfcAlignment entity for each object
                alignment = ifc_file.create_entity("IfcAlignment")
                alignment.Name = f"Alignment {tramif_object.id}"
                alignment.Description = f"PCI: {pci}"

                # Create an IfcAlignmentCurve entity for the geometry
                curve = ifc_file.create_entity("IfcAlignmentCurve")
                curve.Axis = ifc_file.create_entity("IfcCurve")
                curve.Axis.Points = ifc_file.create_entity("IfcPointList")
                curve.Axis.Points.Coordinates = [(coord[0], coord[1], 0) for coord in GEOSGeometry(wkt_geom)]

                # Add the alignment curve to the alignment entity
                alignment.Representation = curve

                # Add the alignment entity to the road
                road.Representation = alignment

            # Write the IFC file
            ifc_file.write("/images/road_test.ifc")
```

But its giving me the error
`Entity with name 'IfcAlignmentCurve' not found in schema 'IFC4X3'`

What I'm doing wrong? Is there any solution? I looked for an example to generate an IFCRoad via IFCOpenShell but there's nothing

Answer (score 0):

The current IFC4.3 version (Add 2) does not define a type `IfcAlignmentCurve`. I think you should set the `IfcCurve` entity directly as an representation item to the `IfcAlignment` entity. This is done via `IfcShapeRepresentation` (collection of multiple product representations) and `IfcRepesentation` (holding a representation context and respective representation items such as curves). Also be aware that `IfcCurve` is abstract. I assume you want to use its subtype `IfcPolyline` which is one of the allowed representation item types for alignment representations.

You can find examples in the official documentation, e.g. [examples for IfcAlignment](https://ifc43-docs.standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/RELEASE/IFC4x3/HTML/lexical/IfcAlignment.htm#5.4.3.1.6-Examples). You may also consult the [developers section of the buildingSMART forum](https://forums.buildingsmart.org/c/developers/) for specific questions related to the schema.